# Jersey Junit java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

Tags: java, rest, intellij-idea, junit, jersey

I'm a newbie with RESTful clients so need some help. I've included my pom file below with the dependencies for a jersey RESTful service.
    
            2.23
            4.3.0.RELEASE
            UTF-8

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Jersey dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Below is the Jersey RESTful client I created to understand how to build such clients.

public class ActivityClient {

```
private Client client;

public ActivityClient(){
    ***client = ClientBuilder.newClient();***
}

public Activity produce(String id){

    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8081/RESTPractice/");

    Activity response = target.path("activities/" + id).request().get(Activity.class);

    return response;
}
```

}

This is my test class for the Jersey client I wrote above.

public class ActivityClientTest {

```
***private ActivityClient client = new ActivityClient();***

@Test
public void checkProduce(){
    Activity activity = client.produce("1234");

    assertThat(activity).isNotNull();
}
```

}

When I run the code on the application server, I have no problems but any time I try to run the test class above, I keep getting the error message below. I've read other similar questions but mostly talking about Selenium projects which isn't what I'm doing here and on Eclipse but I'm using Intellij IDE. The lines in asterisks are the ones highlighted to be throwing the error.Thanks!

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.<init>(ClientConfig.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.<init>(ClientConfig.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder.<init>(JerseyClientBuilder.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:116)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:206)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:86)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:114)
    at com.heg.sammy.client.ActivityClient.<init>(ActivityClient.java:18)
    at com.heg.sammy.client.ActivityClientTest.<init>(ActivityClientTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 40 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Looks like your are missing a [guava](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.guava%7Cguava%7C19.0%7Cbundle) dependency

Comment: I then get this new error after including the guava dependency.    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: this new error sounds like a version mismatch in your dependencies.

Comment: I defined my dependency versions in this property tag of my pom.xml <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.23</jersey.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

Comment: I've looked it up and it says the same thing but can't seem to find the where the mismatch version is